# How disable the spinner in PrinterJob.pringDialog()?

Tags: java, printing

I get the dialog for changing the properties of the print job by invoking the PrinterJob's printDialog() method without any parameter. There is a field where the user can change the the number of copies to be printed on the right-bottom of this dialog.

And now I want to disable this field (the spinner). That is only one copy to be printed and the user can't change it.

Are there any ideas for it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way (or i am not aware of) to modify the native or the cross-platform Java print dialogs (last one might help you a bit). What you could do is maybe display your own dialog (without a spinner field) and under-the-hood do whatever you want (like `PrinterJob.setCopies(1)`).

More info i found [here](http://www.applettalk.com/custom-print-dialog-vt14358.html).

Also, have a look at the [Java tutorial on PrinterJobs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html).